# Manage concurrent requests from single client using QTcpServer/QTcpSocket

Tags: multithreading, qt, sockets

I need to create a TCP client/server app where the (single) client send requests to the server following user commands, but also a periodic "watchdog" message. The watchdog message need to be processed without delay from the server; if the server is processing still processing a previous "heavy" request when a watchdog request arrives, it has to be able to answer the new request ASAP (block the current processing, answer watchdog request (just echo), continue processing).

What's the best approach to get such behavior?

I've read several topics, but I'm not sure which one to follow to get the desired behavior.

**The story so far**

I have a (single) client/server Qt application. I'm managing communication asyncronously using signals/slots.  Client sends a requests, server emit a signal to app when receiving a data, app parse request and do stuffs, then ack/nack the request. The assumption is that the client is sending a single request, waiting for ack/nack before sending a new one.

Everything is working flawlessly so far.

Now I have to add a "watchdog" command, that will be sent periodically (e.g. using a QTimer) by the client, breaking the "single message" assumption. Thought it will work out of the box due to signal/slot Qt management; turns out is not so straightforward...

What happens is that when the user send a "heavy processing request" (can be simplified with a 5 seconds sleep before answering with an ack), the client is also sending the periodic watchdog message (say, every second), but on the server side I get a new dataReady() signal only when the processing is terminated.

I read about threading the socket, via a moveToThread (wasn't able to use this; still getting the "socket from different thread emit" error) or via subclassing QTread (working, but still blocking).

I won't provide a code snippet (at the moment), since it's quite long, even for a minimal example. First, I'll ask you what will be the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is single-threaded and you process heavy request in its slot, `readyRead()` signal get queued in message loop when it's recieved (since only one slot can be processed at a time) and wont be processed until current slot is finished, so server is unable to responce to ping simultaniously. You can 1) call `qApp->processEvents();` while processing heavy request or 2) move processing to another thread (using worker). I'd use second option because code is more readable that way (in my opinion). As a rule of thumb: if you want something be responsive (gui, server, etc) - move heavy things out of the way. Here's crude implementation of second approach: https://github.com/mugiseyebrows/concurrent-requests

Comment: If I get it right, in your (2) option you say that I have to move the single `readReady()` processing to a new thread, not the actual socket (via `moveToThread()`) as I did. Makes sense.